# Bundler installing Git dependencies to wrong directory

Tags: ruby, rubygems, rvm, bundler

I'm having an issue installing Git dependencies with Bundler. `bundle install` appears to finish successfully:

```
Using gemname version from git://github.com/username/repo.git (at master)
Your bundle is complete!
```

However, running any subsequent commands, `bundle exec` etc. it fails:

```
git://github.com/username/repo.git (at master) is not yet checked out. Run `bundle install` first.
```

I have noticed that Bundler has no problem fetching the gem but it is being installed into the local `/home/rails/.bundler/ruby/2.1.0/` directory (and why "Ruby 2.1.0" I don't know...) rather than to where it should be at `/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/` alongside all the other gems.

I've tried clearing out the local Bundler caches and configs and running `bundle install` again in case there was a simple problem there but that hasn't helped.

Gem env:

```
- RUBYGEMS VERSION: 2.2.2
- RUBY VERSION: 2.1.3 (2014-09-19 patchlevel 242) [x86_64-linux]
- INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3
- RUBY EXECUTABLE: /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.3/bin/ruby
- EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/bin
- SPEC CACHE DIRECTORY: /root/.gem/specs
- RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
  - ruby
  - x86_64-linux
- GEM PATHS:
   - /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3
   - /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3@global
- GEM CONFIGURATION:
   - :update_sources => true
   - :verbose => true
   - :backtrace => false
   - :bulk_threshold => 1000
- REMOTE SOURCES:
   - https://rubygems.org/
```

Comment: Are you running `bundle install` with sudo? Are you executing `bundle install` and `bundle exec` using the same user account?

Comment: Same user and yes to running install with sudo. I eventually worked around this problem with the `--deployment` flag but I never figured out the root of the issue.

Comment: Running with sudo means that it isn't the same user :-) You should not ordinarily run `sudo bundle install` as Bundler will invoke sudo internally if necessary to elevate its permissions.

Answer (score 0):

Do not run `sudo bundle install` — this causes git gems to be installed into the wrong location.

When running as a user that can't write to the normal gem installation location (`GEM_HOME`), Bundler expects to find git gems in `$HOME/.bundler`. Installing with `sudo` bypasses this behaviour (because you can write to any location as root), and requires you to also `bundle exec` as root.

Instead run `bundle install` without sudo, as the same user that that will be running `bundle exec`.

If root permissions are required to install other gems, Bundler internally invokes sudo. See http://bundler.io/man/bundle-install.1.html#SUDO-USAGE for details.

Using the `--deployment` flag avoids this issue because in deployment mode all gems (git-sourced and otherwise) are installed into the `vendor/bundle` directory within your project.